# SMTP from gmail webclient and sent folder

Tags: gmail, imap, smtp, dovecot

I want to manage my personal (gmail account) and company mail accounts (not a gmail account) together from my gmail webclient. I know gmail has no support to configure IMAP accounts for external accounts, but that's not a issue for me, at least when receiving messages (I use POP3 for that).

However, my boss, who has also that company account configured in his Outlook using IMAP, wants to see every sent message for monitoring purposes.

So, what I want to do is to "copy" to my "sent messages" mailbox any sent message from my company account from the gmail webclient, and thus my boss can have access to these sent messages in his Outlook.

My server uses postfix and dovecot with a MySQL backend.

Comment: "I know gmail has no support to configure IMAP accounts" - Not so, see [Get started with IMAP and POP3](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018)

Comment: To configure IMAP for your gmail account into another mail client, not to configure another account within the gmail webclient using IMAP.

Comment: If your company gmail account has IMAP enabled then your boss should be able to see everything if he configures outlook to use IMAP **with the same company account**.

Comment: Our company account isn't a gmail account, but a external account.